# Center a dynamically created UIView over a UILabel in the storyboard not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a `UILabel` that is placed on my Storyboard with AutoLayout. (Constraints include *height*, *width* and *center horizontally*, and *vertical spacing from the top*).

I have `UIView` that makes a circle with the `drawRect` method using a `UIBeizerPath`.

Nothing fancy so far.

***For simplicity sake I am using hard coded numbers to help illustrate my problem.***

Now I want the CircleView to be placed over the `UILabel`, centering the label in the circle.

However, I can not get anything to line up correctly. Its like the anchor points or something is messing up.

I tried setting the CircleView's centerpoint to the labels center point. No luck.

I tried setting the CircleViews X to the location of the label minus the width divided by two. No luck.

The closest I can get is with the Y coordinate. I use the label.center.y - 52.5 (half of the radius).

```
cv = [[CircleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(WHATHERE.x, WHATHERE.y,
                                                      155, 155)];
cv.radius           = 75;
cv.strokeWidth      = 5;
```

The radius of the circle is 75. The width/height of the CircleView is 155 because the stroke of the circle is 5. *(radius x 2) + 5*, which give me the view you see with the circle.

[image]

The dark background is the view of the iOS simulator. I have added background colors to each of the elements to distinguish their size.

Through the magic of Photoshop here is what I am trying to accomplish:
[image]

Comment: Where are you creating and adding the circle? I mean which method. Is it in `viewDidLoad` by any chance

Comment: Yeah I'm init the CircleView in the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you're doing something wrong... Use constraints !

Here is my Storyboard label constraints [image]

Here my ViewController

```
    @interface ViewController ()

    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *centeredLabel;

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        CircleView *circleView = [CircleView new];
        [self.view addSubview:circleView];

        circleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        NSLayoutConstraint *circleCenterX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:circleView
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                            toItem:self.centeredLabel
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                                        multiplier:1 constant:0];


        NSLayoutConstraint *circleCenterY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:circleView
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                            toItem:self.centeredLabel
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                        multiplier:1 constant:0];
        CGFloat circleDiameter = 155;

        NSLayoutConstraint *circleWidth = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:circleView
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                            toItem:nil
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                        multiplier:1 constant:circleDiameter];
        NSLayoutConstraint *circleHeight = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:circleView
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                            toItem:circleView
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                                        multiplier:1 constant:0];

        [self.view addConstraints:@[circleCenterX, circleCenterY, circleWidth, circleHeight]];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @end
```

Here's CircleView

```
    @implementation CircleView

- (instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIColor *blueTransparent = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
    [blueTransparent setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.bounds);
    UIColor *circleColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [circleColor setStroke];

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 6);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, self.bounds);

}

@end
```

And here's the result

[image]

Piece of cake ! ;)

Comment: Ding ding ding! That was it. Adding layout Constraints to the CircleView was the ticket! Now can you explain what was going on with my implementation? Why I had add Storyboard layout constraints to a view that wasn't apart of the storyboard?

Comment: I don't understand : constraints in Storyboard only relate to Views embedded in the storyboard, how could you set constraints on a view that wasn't created yet? Note : my code could have worked the same if I created `CircleView` and its constraints directly in my storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Make sure there are no constraints that are potentially pushing the circle
2. Make the circle view a subview of NOT the UILabel, but of the superview (you're probably already doing this)
3. set the circle view's frame to

   ```
   CGRectMake(self.myLabel.frame.origin.x - (155 / 2.0), self.myLabel.frame.origin.y - (155 / 2.0), 155, 155);
   ```

Comment: It's the strangest thing. I am doing or have done all those things. The Label is on the storyboard with constraints. The circle is added programmatically after the view is loaded.

Comment: You should programmatically set the place of the label instead of using constraints. Those constraints are probably pushing the circle away

Comment: @matt has given you the correct solution. Use constraints to position the circle. You are trying to mix auto layout with manually setting the frame of subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Do The init of circle in `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

Comment: When I do this, i can kinda manipulate the circle where it needs to be, however there is a noticeable sudden appearance of the circle after the view loads.